# poner fecha actual en un date y cambiar el calendar picker indicator

Tags: html, css, date, datetime, calendar

tengo el siguiente input:

```
<input type="date" class="formfecha formatofecha  " placeholder=" " name="fec" id="fec" value="20-10-2021"    required/>
```

y tengo puesto el icono del calendario así

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
color: #9e9e9e;
opacity: 0.3;
display: block;
background: url(../img/calendar_mini_icon.png) no-repeat;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
border-width: thin;
margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

1º, me gustaría que cuando cargase el html, pusiese el value de la fecha actual... pero no se me pone ni poniendo value en la etiqueta input... tiene que ser con date ya que si pongo datetime no me aparece el icono del calendario.

2º ya tenia otro inputdate en el html, por lo que necesito seleccionar solo este para ponerle otro icono diferente, pero no se como seleccionar ESTE date concreto con css, ya que tal cual tengo mi css, las propiedades del dibujo afectan a todos los date.
no se si me he explicado...

Answer (score 1):

Me autorespondo:
para seleccionar solo ese calendar-picker pongo:

```
.iconofe::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
```

y para poner la fecha actual, pongo en la etiqueta input

```
value=""
```

y luego con js

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
dd = '0' + dd;
}

if (mm < 10) {
mm = '0' + mm;
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
console.log(today);

function fechaact(){
var fe = document.getElementById('fechactual');
fe.value = today;
}
fechaact();
```